# Форматирование фонового изображения

Tags: html, css

Как можно форматировать картинку на бекграунде? То есть мне нужно сделать картинку фоном, а потом на ней писать текст.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочтите [это](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background)
А вообще, стоит делать [так](http://www.google.ru/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0+html)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-image: url('изображение.jpeg')"
     <p>Какое-то текст</p>
</div>
```

В этом примере:
width - ширина области у которой будет бэкграунд;
height - высота;
url - путь к изображению;

В div уже пишется текст. И таким образом будет эффект того, что на картинке пишется текст. Примерно так :)